# Lotus Notes - sending Form in email

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

My question is how is it possible to send a form (developed in Domino Designer) via email?

I followed [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_STORING_FORMS_OVER.html) guide and set up the necessary form & database properties, but when i click "Preview in Notes" i still can not forward/send my form (as an email) via a new message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've followed the directions that you linked, then a button that uses @MailSend with no arguments will send the email with its stored form. But the receiving user's mailbox must have the "Allow use of stored forms in this database." property checked, otherwise the stored form will be ignored.

See [my answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824833/how-do-i-get-lotus-notes-mailsend-to-send-an-exact-copy-of-my-form) for more details.

Answer (score -3):

As it turns out, you can not do such. You have to send the form from lotusscript.

Comment: Did you check @Mailsend?

Comment: Why do you want to send a form?  That seems like an odd thing to do.

Comment: It used to be a very common thing to do, back in the 90s.

Comment: And it does not require LotusScript. It requires use of the Store Form in Document feature. We were able to email forms back in Notes 3.0, before LotusScript was even available.

Comment: just out of curiosity. why the 3 downvotes? Eitherway. What i meant by "not being possible" is to send it from the preview in lotus notes. The solution i have at the moment is that i hardcode the recipients in the end and then call a "document.Send(True True)" . That is what i meant by "Sending it from lotus script". If someone has a better solution, i'm all ears. P.S.: Sorry for the short, not so descriptive answer above. I was in a hurry

Comment: The downvotes are because you don't need Lotusscript. You can do it with @MailSend.